# How to swap arrayMap values and keys in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, key-value

I'm having a bit of trouble reversing a given map and storing its reversed keys and values into another map. I have a method prototype as follows:

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> reverse (Map <String, Set<String>> graph);
```

So if I have sample keys for the directed graph such that:

```
{c -> arraySet{f, e}}
{b -> d}
{a -> arraySet{c, b}} 
{d -> g}
{e -> d}
{f -> arraySet{g, d}}
```

I need to effectively reverse this graph so that instead of b -> d I have d -> b.

I think all this requires is for me is to interchange the values and keys in the original graph and add them to the reverseMap. I suppose I could iterate through each set of values for a given key in the graph and then and store those in a list.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble implementing this and thinking it through. I'd really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: You might be interested in Guava's [Multimaps](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to loop over the entries in your map, and then, since the values are stored in a set, you will need to loop over that set. You will need to check your result map for each key and create a new set whenever a key does not yet exist.

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> reverse (Map <String, Set<String>> graph) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> result = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> graphEntry: graph.entrySet()) {
        for (String graphValue: graphEntry.getValue()) {
            Set<String> set = result.get(graphValue);
            if (set == null) {
                set = new HashSet<String>();
                result.put(graphValue, set);
            }
            set.add(graphEntry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This would become a lot clearer if you used a Multimap instead of a Map.

Comment: You're also doing 2 lookups (containsKey() and get()) when a single get() with a null check would give the same result. Using a Multimap eliminates that.

Comment: Good points. Cleaned it up, but leaving the answer in case he can't use Guava for some reason.

Comment: This was great! I prefer this solution to the others. Although Guava is nice, I prefer this implementation. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's actual, working, up-to-date code using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) Multimaps:

```
SetMultimap<Integer, Integer> graph = HashMultimap.create();
graph.put(1, 2); // add an edge from 1 to 2
SetMultimap<Integer, Integer> inverse = Multimaps.invertFrom(
  graph, HashMultimap.<Integer, Integer> create());
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

But if you can't use third-party libraries, do something like this...

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> g;
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> gInverse = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> gAdj : g.entrySet()) {
  Integer v = gAdj.getKey();
  for (Integer w : gAdj.getValue()) {
    Set<Integer> wInverseAdj = gInverse.get(w);
    if (wInverseAdj == null) {
      gInverse.put(w, wInverseAdj = new HashSet<Integer>());
    }
    wInverseAdj.add(v);
  }
}
```

Or if you can use Java 8, use this...

```
map.entrySet().stream()
   .flatMap(entryKToVs -> entryKToVs.getValue().stream()
       .map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entryKToVs.getKey(), str)))
   .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())))
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode, but close to real. Just use a [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html).

```
Multimap<String, String> ret = Multimaps.newSetMultimap();
for (Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : graph) {
  for(String neighbor : entry.getValue()) {
    ret.addTo(neighbor, entry.getKey());
  }
}
```

Comment: Love the idea of leveraging good libraries so you don't have to solve already solved problems!

Comment: Your doc link is several years out of date, but why not just use `Multimaps.invertFrom` while you're at it?

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest writing a `Graph` class which abstracts away the underlying `Map` data structure.  Of course, this just pushes the implementation to the `Graph` interface rather than dealing directly with the `Map` interface.

So for now, stick with your map:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> graph;
Map<String, Set<String>> reverse;
```

I suggest using [Map.entrySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) to get the set of entries from your `graph`. Then for each [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html), retrieve the key and value of each one. Next, for each "vertex" in the value `Set`, insert the key into the `Set` which is associated with the vertex.

This might be more clear if I formatted it similar to Java code rather than English sentences. I hope you get the basic idea. Of course, using a pre-made and pre-tested solution would be preferrable if it fits into your constraints of project.

Comment: Both maps are Map<String, Set<String>>, it's not a bijective map.

Comment: @FrankPavageau ahh...I misunderstood. The OP is reversing the edges in the graph, not reversing the mapping relationship of the data structure.